# How to insert empty excel dates into oracle with Python+Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, oracle, pandas

I've got a Python application that is using pandas to grok some excel spreadsheets and insert values into an oracle database.

For date cells that have a value, this works fine. For empty date cells I am inserting a NaT, which I would have thought would be fine, but in Oracle that is becoming some weird invalid time that displays as "0001-255-255 00:00:00" (Something like MAXINT or 0 being converted to a timestamp I'm guessing?)

```
In[72]: x.iloc[0][9]
Out[72]: NaT
```

Above is the bit of data in the DataFrame, you can see it's a NaT.

But this is what I see in Oracle..

```
SQL> select TDATE from TABLE where id=5067 AND version=5;

TDATE
---------
01-NOVEMB

SQL> select dump("TDATE") TABLE where id=5067 AND version=5;

DUMP("TDATE")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=12 Len=7: 100,101,255,255,1,1,1
```

I tried doing df.replace and/or df.where to convert NaT to None but I get assorted errors with either of these that seem to imply the substitution is not valid in that way.

Any way to ensure consistency of a null date across these datastores?!

Comment: How do you insert your date value in the DB? What is the type of the date column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see my answer, and if you have any outstanding questions, please comment it on my answer:-)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux In[231]: x['TDATE'].dtype Out[229]: dtype('<M8[ns]')  - ie, datetime64[ns]

Comment: I tried for almost 1/2h, but I was unable to reproduce that behavior (i.e.: "faking" a date to produce the same "dump" a you). Do you use [DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to send the dataframe to the DB? Or something else?

Comment: No, for reasons too esoteric to get into I'm massaging the DataFrame a bit and actually executing sql directly with a cursor. Given that you are not seeing the wierdness with .to_sql it's probably worth me testing that method. If it works I can work around the issues that led me to use a cursor instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue has been fixed in Pandas 15.0.**

If you can, update to Pandas >= 15.0. Starting with that version, `NaN` and `NaT` are properly stored as NULL in the database.

---

After having performed some experiments, it appears that Pandas pass `NaT` to SQLAlchemy and down to cx_Oracle -- which in its turn blindly send an *invalid date* to Oracle (which in its turn does not complain).

Anyway, one I was able to come with is to add a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` to fix incoming timestamps. For that to work, you will have to manually create the table first.

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE W ("ID" NUMBER(5), "TDATE" TIMESTAMP);
```

And then the trigger:

```
-- Create a trigger on the table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fix_null_ts
BEFORE INSERT ON W
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (extract(month from new.tdate) = 255)
BEGIN
  :new.tdate := NULL;
END;
/
```

After that, from Python, using [`pandas.DataFrame.toSql(..., if_exists='append')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
>>> d = [{"id":1,"tdate":datetime.now()},{"id":2}]
>>> f = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> f.to_sql("W",engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
#                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#          don't drop the table! append data to an existing table
```

And check:

```
>>> result = engine.execute("select * from w")
>>> for row in result:
...     print(row)
... 
(1, datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 1, 10, 2))
(2, None)
```

---

Beware that, if you ever need to rewrite an other DataFrame to the same table, you will first need to delete its content -- but not drop it, otherwise you would loose the trigger at the same time. For example:

```
# Some new data
>>> d = [{"id":3}]
>>> f = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Truncate the table and write the new data
>>> engine.execute("truncate table w")
>>> f.to_sql("W",engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
>>> result = engine.execute("select * from w")

# Check the result
>>> for row in result:
...     print(row)
... 
(3, None)
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I can't upgrade pandas just yet (too close to a release to uprev a major component at the moment), using a bunch of the pointers you gave I was able to overcome the issue in the short term. Long term upreving pandas is on the plan already, so that will be even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the data type of the date column in Oracle database is `DATE`.

In that case, remember, date has a date part and time part together as THE DATE. While loading into database, make sure you use `TO_DATE` and put a proper datetime format to the date literal.

That's about loading. Now, to display, use `TO_CHAR` with proper datetime format to see the value the way the human eyes want to see a datetime value.

And, regarding the `NULL` values, unless you have `NOT NULL` constraint, I don't see any issue with loading. The `NULL` values would anyway loaded as NULL. If you want to manipulate the `NULL` values, use `NVL` function and use the desired value you want to replace the NULL value with.

Comment: _"I hope the data type of the date column in Oracle database is DATE."_ According to the `DUMP` output it is as [data type 12 is `DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#sthref37)